# Trigger bootstrap modal confirm message on successful login

Tags: php, forms, session, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am just getting started with Bootstrap and am loving it, but I can not figure out how to trigger the modal window based on a successful login. The form should set the session. The modal contains confirmation copy like "are you sure you want to proceed, etc..." with a proceed button linking to the protected page. The 2 things work fine separately (login/modal) but I can't figure out how to combine them and trigger the modal only after the session is successfully set.

I have a login form...

```
<form method="post" class="form-signin well">
    <input type="text" id="uname" class="input-block-level" name="uname" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="ch" value="login">
    <?php   
        if(isset($_SESSION['login_msg'])){
        echo '<span class="alert alert-error">Login failed. Please try again.</span>';
        unset($_SESSION['login_msg']);
    ?>
</form>
```

login script...

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'login'){
    if($_REQUEST['uname'] == 'username' && $_REQUEST['pass'] == 'password')
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = 1;
else
         $_SESSION['login_msg'] = 1;
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['index']))
$pagename = $_REQUEST['index'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'logout'){
    unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
    header('Location:index.php');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
if(isset($_REQUEST['index']))
    header('Location:'.$pagename.'.php');
else
    header('Location:protectedpage.php');
}
else{
?>
```

and my model (header removed to keep it short)...

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This site is intended solely for...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="protectedpage.php" class="btn btn-success">Agree to Proceed</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried different combinations of things including changing the submit button to something like this...

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-toggle="modal">Sign In</a>
```

but that didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. firstly, i suggest you change your button type to

   Sign In

then using jquery.valition for validation.like below:

```
 $("#signinForm").validate({

                // Specify the validation rules
                rules: {
                    inputUser: "required",
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    }
                },


                // Specify the validation error messages
                messages: {
                    inputUser: "Please enter your first name",
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {

                    form.submit();
                }
            });
```

via jquery, you can see here it have a sumithandler, so can do anything you like, like:

```
$('#signinForm').find("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", true).attr("value",
```

"Submitting...");

or pop up something you like.